# Google does not indexing data from api on page

Tags: docker, ubuntu, strapi, google-search-console

In google index I can see my page indexed, but with fetching data error. In Google Search Console when I test page url (active version) I can see correct content. When I visit the page all is correct as well - no errors, all data fetched and displayed. However in google the page is indexed without data fetched (display fetching data error in description). When I check the content of indexed page in Google Search Console  there is the fetching data error content (as display in google search).

While ago, when I tested the page in live Google Search Console, the first attempt showed server error (as in Google index), but every next call showed correct, full loaded, page. It makes me think, that there is some standby mode, but I not noticed it before - server was always ready to work immediately.

Point out that this is my own server with Ubuntu Server (not sure, i guess 19.XX) installed. Api (Strapi.io) is running in docker container. May there be default "standby" mode or something like that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: Oh, I understand. However maybe it is connected with Ubuntu Server / Docker / Strapi as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

When you say *the page is indexed without data fetched* are you talking about the rendered HTML that you can see using the URL Inspection tool from Search Console?

It's hard to make an assesment without knowing the specific URL you are talking about. Depending on how long it takes your server to respond to the fetch request, Googlebot might consider killing the connection.

However, I would say that the testing tools from Google, like the URL Inspector tool from Google Search Console, have lower times thresholds than the "real" Googlebot because the testing tools prioritise to give you results quick. Hence, it might be a limitation from the testing tool.

If the data that you're fetching it's really imporant it might be worth considering dynamic rendering for Googlebot. Serving a pre-rendered version of the page to Googlebot and let the users have the real experience.

Comment: I mean that Google indexed Server error message instead content - it is react singe page application. I prerendered it using react-snap, but it call api when user enter anyway. Url: https://erys.io/blog and subpaths